# SystemEventListener + @Value null on Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

I am facing a problem in one SystemEventListener that I implemented. I am using the annotation @Value to inject a value from a properties file. The problem is the annotation @Value is working well in other parts of the application such as a @Controller but in this SystemEventListener is not working well. Also it is working on tomcat but not on Websphere 8.5.

Do you know what it could be?

**Implementation**

```
public class PreRenderViewListener implements SystemEventListener {

    @Value("${path}/fileName.properties")
    private String filePath;
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<system-event-listener>
            <system-event-listener-class>com.package.PreRenderViewListener</system-event-listener-class>
            <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent</system-event-class>
</system-event-listener>
```

The resolver is a bean which extends the class `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`which is working well.

```
<bean id="uxMasterConfigBean" class="com.csc.cscip.ux.common.util.UXPropertiesConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/resources/master/ux.default.configuration.properties</value>
                <value>${ux.master.configuration.file.path}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This configuration is working well in Tomcat so I don't think it is a problem in the code, maybe it is a problem related with Websphere 8.5. I have been looking for this issue on Internet but I haven't found anything like this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would be surprised that it would work, basically the behavior as in WebSphere is what I would expect to happen. The `PreRenderViewListener` is a JSF (faces) managed bean and not a spring managed bean so `@Value` shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum said,

> The PreRenderViewListener is a JSF (faces) managed bean and not a
>   spring managed bean so @Value shouldn't work.

So for you to get it work, you must make your `PreRenderViewListener` "recognised" by Spring, which means, it must be a Spring component.
A solution that I'm using right now (and I hope to get remarks about it) is to use a `multicaster` like `org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingPhaseListenerMulticaster` that will be registered in faces config and will delegate all work to other Spring beans that implement `SystemEventListener`.
Here is the code for the multicaster (it's inspired from the mentioned Spring multicaster).

```
package org.example.listeners;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.event.SystemEvent;
import javax.faces.event.SystemEventListener;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils;


public class DelegatingSystemEventListenerMulticaster implements SystemEventListener{

@Override
public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    for (SystemEventListener listener : getDelegates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())) {
        if(listener.isListenerForSource(event.getSource())){
            listener.processEvent(event);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
    for (SystemEventListener listener : getDelegates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())) {
        if(listener.isListenerForSource(source)){
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


/**
 * Obtain the delegate PhaseListener beans from the Spring root WebApplicationContext.
 * @param facesContext the current JSF context
 * @return a Collection of PhaseListener objects
 * @see #getBeanFactory
 * @see org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory#getBeansOfType(Class)
 */
protected Collection<SystemEventListener> getDelegates(FacesContext facesContext) {
    ListableBeanFactory bf = getBeanFactory(facesContext);
    return BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(bf, SystemEventListener.class, true, false).values();
}

/**
 * Retrieve the Spring BeanFactory to delegate bean name resolution to.
 * <p>The default implementation delegates to {@code getWebApplicationContext}.
 * Can be overridden to provide an arbitrary ListableBeanFactory reference to
 * resolve against; usually, this will be a full Spring ApplicationContext.
 * @param facesContext the current JSF context
 * @return the Spring ListableBeanFactory (never {@code null})
 * @see #getWebApplicationContext
 */
protected ListableBeanFactory getBeanFactory(FacesContext facesContext) {
    return getWebApplicationContext(facesContext);
}

/**
 * Retrieve the web application context to delegate bean name resolution to.
 * <p>The default implementation delegates to FacesContextUtils.
 * @param facesContext the current JSF context
 * @return the Spring web application context (never {@code null})
 * @see FacesContextUtils#getRequiredWebApplicationContext
 */
protected WebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext facesContext) {
    return FacesContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(facesContext);
}

}
```

In `faces-config.xml`:

```
<system-event-listener>
        <system-event-listener-class>org.example.listeners.DelegatingSystemEventListenerMulticaster</system-event-listener-class>
<!--Use any event you want here -->
        <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PostAddToViewEvent</system-event-class>
    </system-event-listener>
```

And then finally, create your `SystemEventListener` beans, for example:

```
@Component
public class FooComponentListener  implements SystemEventListener{

@Autowired
private FooService fooService;

@Override
public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    //Do your business
}

@Override
public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
//Or any other condition
    return (source instanceof HtmlInputText || source instanceof HtmlOutputText || source instanceof HtmlOutputLabel);
}


}
```

I hope this will be of some help, even if a little late.